Iterating Json attributes and PSCustom Objects
I am looking into iterating json attributes and values from a json file w/out prior knowledge of the schema. I have code that works with many of the json files or downloads I have tested, but draw blanks when it comes to iterating nested values. I have looked at various posts that  use Get-Member and .psobject.name and NoteProperty... but all seemed to have prior knowledge of the json content. I tested this
{
  "FoodChoices": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "TakeOut",
      "variableGroups": [],
      "variables": {
        "Location": {
          "value": "Fast Food"
        },
        "Beverage": {
          "value": "Soda or Lemondade"
        },
        "Tip": {
          "value": "No Way"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Gourmet",
      "variableGroups": [],
      "variables": {
        "Location": {
          "value": "Nice Resturant"
        },
        "Beverage": {
          "value": "Dirty Martini"
        },
        "Tip": {
          "value": "Maybe"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

but had to kludge the iteration
$jfile = "$PSScriptRoot\FoodChoice.json"

$file = Get-Content $jFile -Raw
$parse = ($file.substring(0,1) -ne "[")
$json = $file | ConvertFrom-Json

$parent = $json | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
if ($parse -eq $true)
{
   foreach ($p in $parent)
   {
      $d = $json.$p
      if ($d.length -gt 1) { $data = $d }
   }
}
else {$data = $json }
$out = "Key" + "`t" + "Value" + "`n"
$keys = $data | get-member -type properties | Foreach-Object name
foreach ($d in $data)
{
   foreach ($k in $keys)
   {
       $name = $d.$k
       if ($name -match "@")
       {
           $out += "$k`t`n"
           $members = Get-Member -InputObject $name
           foreach ($m in $members)
           {
              if ($m -match "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject")
              {
                 $m1 = $m.ToString()
                 $m1 = $m1.Replace("System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject","") 
                 if ($m1 -match "@")
                 {
                    $m1 = $m1.Replace("@{","")
                    $m1 = $m1.Replace("}","")
                    $m1 = $m1 -split "="
                    $m2 = $m1[0]
                    $m3 = $m1[2]
                    $out += "$m2`t$m3`n"
                 }
                 else {$out += "$name`t$m1`n"}
              }
           }
       }
       else {$out += "$k`t$name`n"}
   }
}
$out
Exit


Hopefully there is a generic way to parse out nested attributes with type of System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject.
The script outputs
Key Value
id  1
name    TakeOut
variableGroups  
variables   
 Beverage   Soda or Lemondade
 Location   Fast Food
 Tip    No Way
id  2
name    Gourmet
variableGroups  
variables   
 Beverage   Dirty Martini
 Location   Nice Resturant
 Tip    Maybe


Just to be clear, are you wanting a tool that gives you info on the structure of a JSon?  In other words, an automated way to show how to navigate various JSon files?

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779762/iterating-through-key-names-from-a-pscustomobject yet does not address your nested portion.

This might be what you were looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970079/how-to-recursively-enumerate-through-properties-of-object

Before answering your question, I like to start with a few comments and asides:

Your variable naming is somewhat confusing, what you call $json ($file | ConvertFrom-Json) has no relation anymore with Json, it is a PowerShell Object(-Graph) containing collections as arrays (@()) and PSCustomObjects(1) ([PSCustomObject]@{}) or HashTables (@{}) that contain other collections or scalars as strings and primitives. For a similar reason is the $file variable somewhat confusing as that has no relation anymore with file except for the content (consider: $Content or even explicit the Json string (actually $Json).

For details about the PSCustomObject, see:


About PSCustomObject
Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject


Using the increase assignment operator (+=) to build a string is inefficient, see this answer and Performance Considerations / String Addition

If you using PowerShell 6 or newer, there is no need to use PSCustomObjects, instead you might use the -AsHashTable parameter which returns HashTables. A HashTable is a little easier to handle than a PSCustomObject.


This last comment actually shows that there isn't much difference between a PSCustomObject and a HashTable (or even any dictionary) if it comes to an object-graph. Meaning, when converting an object-graph back to Json string (using e.g.: ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99) you will get the same results. Hance my propose to: Make PSCustomObject more Dictionary alike (#20591)
Btw, a similar behavior exists for arrays where ConvertTo-Json converts anything that supports the IList interface to an Json array.
So basically there exist only 3 types of node structures:

Map nodes
everything that supports the IDictionary interface, (as HashTable, Ordered and Dictionary[string,string]) and certain objects (as the PSCustomObject and a ComponentModel.Component).
List nodes
Arrays and everything that supports the IList interface.
Note that ConvertFrom-Json cmdlet returns a object-graph based on fixed size arrays which are awkward if it comes to modifying to modifying them, yet the ConvertTo-Json cmdlet simply supports List objects instead of arrays. Hence the propose: Add -AsList switch to ConvertFrom-Json (#24010)
Leaf nodes
A scalar (as a string or a primitive) that resides at the end of each (embedded) collection branch.

In other words: a "generic way to parse out nested attributes" should in my opinion accept just these 3 structures without being strict on the underlying .Net type.
One of my first concepts resides in this answer which you might use to recursively iterate to the whole Object-Graph tree yourself if you do not want to rely on a custom module.
Anyways, the ObjectGraphTools set might already be helpful for a exploring an object-graph were e.g. the convenient Member-Access Enumeration feature often lead to a pitfall during recursive iteration. For this, you might use the Get-ChildNode cmdlet:
$Object = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json
$Object | Get-ChildNode -Recurse -Leaf

Path                                    Name  Depth             Value
----                                    ----  -----             -----
FoodChoices[0].id                       id        3                 1
FoodChoices[0].name                     name      3           TakeOut
FoodChoices[0].variables.Location.value value     5         Fast Food
FoodChoices[0].variables.Beverage.value value     5 Soda or Lemondade
FoodChoices[0].variables.Tip.value      value     5            No Way
FoodChoices[1].id                       id        3                 2
FoodChoices[1].name                     name      3           Gourmet
FoodChoices[1].variables.Location.value value     5    Nice Resturant
FoodChoices[1].variables.Beverage.value value     5     Dirty Martini
FoodChoices[1].variables.Tip.value      value     5             Maybe

Or to build a PowerShell expression template using the Copy-ObjectGraph and ConvertTo-Expression cmdlets:
$Object | Copy-ObjectGraph -ListAs Collections.Generic.List[object] -MapAs Ordered |
    ConvertTo-Expression -LanguageMode Full

[ordered]@{
    FoodChoices = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]]@(
        [ordered]@{
            id = [long]1
            name = [string]'TakeOut'
            variableGroups = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]]@()
            variables = [ordered]@{
                Location = [ordered]@{ value = [string]'Fast Food' }
                Beverage = [ordered]@{ value = [string]'Soda or Lemondade' }
                Tip = [ordered]@{ value = [string]'No Way' }
            }
        },
        [ordered]@{
            id = [long]2
            name = [string]'Gourmet'
            variableGroups = [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]]@()
            variables = [ordered]@{
                Location = [ordered]@{ value = [string]'Nice Resturant' }
                Beverage = [ordered]@{ value = [string]'Dirty Martini' }
                Tip = [ordered]@{ value = [string]'Maybe' }
            }
        }
    )
}

And in case you do want to adopt this module, you could iterate through the whole object-graph in several ways:
Reclusive iteration
By creating a function that calls itself, e.g.:
function Iterate([PSNode]$Node) { # Basic iterator
    if ($Node -is [PSLeafNode]) {
        "{0}{1}: {2}" -f (' ' * $Node.Depth), $Node.Name, $Node.Value 
    }
    else {
        $Node.ChildNodes.foreach{ Iterate $_ }
    }
}

$Object = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json
$PSNode = [PSNode]::ParseInput($Object)
Iterate $PSNode

   id: 1
   name: TakeOut
     value: Fast Food
     value: Soda or Lemondade
     value: No Way
   id: 2
   name: Gourmet
     value: Nice Resturant
     value: Dirty Martini
     value: Maybe

Flat iteration
Knowing that PowerShell functions are somewhat expensive (see this post), you might consider to do a "flat iteration" instead (which has an equal output):
$LeafNodes = $Object | Get-ChildNode -Recurse -Leaf
foreach ($Node in $LeafNodes) {
    "{0}{1}: {2}" -f (' ' * $Node.Depth), $Node.Name, $Node.Value 
}

No iteration
In some cases you may not need to iterate at all, e.g. where want to lookup the tip of all "Fast Food" locations. For this I designed a Extended Dot Notation (Xdn) similar to XPath for XML objects which you might use together with the Get-Node cmdlet:
$Object | Get-Node ~*="Fast Food"...Tip.Value

Path                               Name  Depth Value
----                               ----  ----- -----
FoodChoices[0].variables.Tip.value value     5 No Way

To modify the concerned node value (in your example), you could do this:
($Object | Get-Node ~*="Fast Food"...Tip.Value).Value = 'Never'

Or in case it concerns multiple Tip.Value nodes, it would be:
$Object | Get-Node ~*="Fast Food"...Tip.Value | ForEach-Object { $_.Value = 'Never' }

Where
$Object | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9 # Results in:



{
  "FoodChoices": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "TakeOut",
  "variableGroups": [],
  "variables": {
    "Location": {
      "value": "Fast Food"
    },
    "Beverage": {
      "value": "Soda or Lemondade"
    },
    "Tip": {
      "value": "Never"
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Gourmet",
  "variableGroups": [],
  "variables": {
    "Location": {
      "value": "Nice Resturant"
    },
    "Beverage": {
      "value": "Dirty Martini"
    },
    "Tip": {
      "value": "Maybe"
    }
  }
}
  ]
}




I do not see any issue in handling the json. However I think the major way to handle key/value JSON in powershell would be to use convertFrom-Json
$jsondata = Get-Content D:\Scripts\jason_sample.txt

$jsondata | ConvertFrom-Json #Should give you all the child underneath and you can expand also. 

($jsondata | ConvertFrom-Json).FoodChoices ## should give you all the id, name , etc 

If you are still struggling with it then initially you can handle that with  [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_)
$jsondata | ConvertTo-Json | % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } | Out-File "File.json" -Force


Consider the following example.
function Resolve-Properties($inputObject, $maxLevels=5, $Level=0){

  process {
    if($Level -eq 0){
        Write-Host "Key`tValue"
    } else {
        for($i = 0; $i -lt $level; $i++){
            Write-Host "`t" -NoNewline
        }
    }
    
    foreach($prop in $InputObject.PSObject.Properties){
      if($prop.Value.Count -eq 0){
        Write-Host "$($prop.Name)`t[EmptyObj]"
      } elseif($prop.TypeNameOfValue -match "Object"){
        Write-Host "$($prop.Name)`t[Object]"
        if($level -lt $maxLevels){
          foreach($s in $prop.Value){
            Resolve-Properties -InputObject $s -Level ($level + 1)
          }
        }
      } else {
        Write-Host "$($prop.Name)`t$($prop.Value)"
      }
    }
  }
}

$file = '{
  "FoodChoices": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "TakeOut",
      "variableGroups": [],
      "variables": {
        "Location": {
          "value": "Fast Food"
        },
        "Beverage": {
          "value": "Soda or Lemondade"
        },
        "Tip": {
          "value": "No Way"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Gourmet",
      "variableGroups": [],
      "variables": {
        "Location": {
          "value": "Nice Resturant"
        },
        "Beverage": {
          "value": "Dirty Martini"
        },
        "Tip": {
          "value": "Maybe"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}'

$parse = ($file.substring(0,1) -ne "[")
$json = $file | ConvertFrom-Json

$parent = $json | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
if ($parse -eq $true){
   foreach ($p in $parent)   {
      $d = $json.$p
      if ($d.length -gt 1) { $data = $d }
   }
} else {
    $data = $json
}

Clear

$data | ForEach-Object {
    Resolve-Properties $_
}

This is based off of the example found here: How to recursively enumerate through properties of object?
This iterates the Objects and recursively displays them with an additional Tab character added for each level.
Output
Key Value
id  1
name    TakeOut
variableGroups  [EmptyObj]
variables   [Object]
    Location    [Object]
        value   Fast Food
Beverage    [Object]
        value   Soda or Lemondade
Tip [Object]
        value   No Way
Key Value
id  2
name    Gourmet
variableGroups  [EmptyObj]
variables   [Object]
    Location    [Object]
        value   Nice Resturant
Beverage    [Object]
        value   Dirty Martini
Tip [Object]
        value   Maybe

